# How can I align text to a baseline grid using reportlab's platypus?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, platypus

In DTP software you can set up a baseline grid and force all the text in a document to be aligned to baselines (example here with [inDesign](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89mQBYHwt_E)). Is there a simple way to achieve this with reportlab's platypus? I didn't find any option in the documentation so my guess is there is no option for that. In that case what would be my best option to combine the facilities offered by platypus (text justification, hyphenation, frames, flowables, etc ...) with custom code to implement baseline grid alignment ? Would I have to implement my own frames for example?